# Usage of lucene's MultiFieldQueryParser

Tags: java, lucene

In lucene 5.3, while trying to use `MultiFieldQueryParser` to parse a raw string into a `Query` instance, and do search, then it seems the search result is not correct.

**Data**:

There is a document with `city` field as `Venice`.

**Code**:

```
public void testQueryParser() throws IOException, ParseException {
    QueryParser parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(new String[] { "city" }, new SimpleAnalyzer());
    Query query = parser.parse("Venice");

    IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(getReader());
    TopDocs docs = searcher.search(query, 10);
    assertEquals(1, docs.totalHits); // FIXME ... seems failed,
}
```

The above junit expect the totalHits to be `1`, but get `0`.

Any help? thanks.

Comment: Is the actual, post-analysis content of the field `Venice`?  If so, your problem is your analyzer.  `SimpleAnalyzer` includes lowercasing.  Make sure you are using the same Analyzer when you index the field *and* when you search it.

Comment: @femtoRgon Yes, great tip. The indexing part was using `WhitespaceAnalyzer`, after change them to the same analyzer, the junit test passed.